# sort two dimension array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

I need to sort two dimension array in  Ascending order ,I write this code in C# to sort array but it sort each line in array not all two dimension array , How can I sort all two dimension array

```
        double[,] test_Descriptor = new double[3, 3];

        double tempr;

        test_Descriptor[0,0]=7;
        test_Descriptor[1, 0] = 7;
        test_Descriptor[2, 0] = 5;
        test_Descriptor[0, 1] = 3;
        test_Descriptor[1, 1] = 0;
        test_Descriptor[2, 1] = 2;
        test_Descriptor[0, 2] = 1;
        test_Descriptor[1, 2] = 9;
        test_Descriptor[2, 2] = 1;


        for (int i = 0; i < test_Descriptor.GetLength(0); i++) // Array Sorting
        {
            for (int j = test_Descriptor.GetLength(1) - 1; j > 0; j--)
            {

                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                {
                    if (test_Descriptor[i, k] > test_Descriptor[i, k + 1])
                    {
                        tempr = test_Descriptor[i, k];
                        test_Descriptor[i, k] = test_Descriptor[i, k + 1];
                        test_Descriptor[i, k + 1] = tempr;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                Console.WriteLine("y={0}", test_Descriptor[x,y]);

     }
```

Comment: First you need to decide what it means to sort a two-dimensional array.  If your array is { { 4, 2 }, { 3, 1 } } then is the result { { 1, 3 }, { 2, 4 } }?  Is it { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }?  Is it something else?

Comment: Do you want the elements to appear in non-decreasing order in row-major fashion? As an aside, why don't you use `Array.Sort` method which will be much faster than bubble sort you're using in your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting a true 2D array is difficult, because the sorting algorithm must take into account the 2D structure of the array. You would be better off if you

- Make a plain array of size `tmp[M*N]`,
- Copy the data into `tmp`
- Sort `tmp`
- Copy the sorted data back into the original array

Here is how you can do it:

```
double tmp[test_Descriptor.GetLength(0)*test_Descriptor.GetLength(1)];
for (int i = 0; i != test_Descriptor.GetLength(0); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j != test_Descriptor.GetLength(1); j++) {
        tmp[i*test_Descriptor.GetLength(1)+j] = test_Descriptor[i, j];
    }
}
Array.sort(tmp);
for (int i = 0; i != test_Descriptor.GetLength(0); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j != test_Descriptor.GetLength(1); j++) {
        test_Descriptor[i, j] = tmp[i*test_Descriptor.GetLength(1)+j];
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works for one possible definition of what it means to sort a 2D array, of course.

Comment: @phoog True. However, "the definition of what it means to sort in 2D" could be tweaked to a certain extent by changing the step of copying the data back.

Comment: The other likely definition, it seems, would be to copy the 2D array to a jagged array, sort each inner array, and then sort the outer array.

Comment: -1 until we know what the OP means by "sort a 2D array". That might get reversed later, but an incomplete question cannot, by definition, have a good answer.

Comment: @ClickRick "incomplete question cannot, by definition, have a good answer." By the same token such answers cannot be considered "bad", so the consistency of the reasoning behind your downvote is questionable. By the way, you would be surprised how many questions on Stack Overflow are answered on a good guess of the question :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I might not have been active on the site for long, but I'd not be at all surprised. Tag me again if the question changes and I'll reassess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quickest solution through Linq: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/166236/Sorting-a-Two-Dimensional-Array-in-Csharp

Comment: flagged your comments as you don't seems to be helping user. At least I tried to help through external link which is quite explanatory.

Comment: I'm explaining what a "better answer" would look like. How is that not constructive?

Comment: if you have to clear your doubt on question then you are welcome to ask the same - many of us answer the question by guessing the doubt... seems you don't get that idea well! So raise your concerns with the questioner not helpers!! anyways, good luck.

Comment: +1 as you did not deserve the -1